# Magical Combat with Flowing Magical Energy

Tags: magic

So for my world (Which I am building for a book I'm writing), magic exists, and Aeritheans (Earth humans) are studying it closely, even though most people on Damarian at least understand the basics of how it works (Who said that a whole unit on it in 9th grade science class was useless?).

On Damarian, magic works by elemental energies, based on the elements of Air, Darkness, Death, Earth, Fire, Ice, Life, Light, Psyche, Storm, War, and Water. Spellcasters are rare enough that for the average Joe off the street, meeting a mage is like seeing a rainbow: Possible to see it numerous times, but not an everyday occurrence. For numbers, there are roughly 100 mages per 10,000 people born (Ratio of mage births to regular Joe and Jill births are 1:100, so a 1% chance). However, most people born mages never unlock that power: It takes learned skill to fully manipulate magic, and that's assuming great conditions, with all the magical energy you need where you are, which it isn't (More on that later). A mage must be surrounded fully in magical energy to cast a spell successfully. If the energy fades, the mage cannot cast spells of the type the energy was, and any spells in the process of casting when the magic fades is lost.

The italicized text is not important; You can skip it if you want.

*Thus, the number of actual mages to Joes and Jills is 1 per 10,000, or 0.01% (0.0001 of all people). The other 99 of 10,000 don't get the education, or deny it and suppress it, sometimes to the point of losing the gift totally, or at least making it harder to manifest it. The gift is somewhat genetic, so two mages have a higher chance of having a magical baby, on the upward swing to 1 out of 250 mage-born babies (Babies born to mage-mage couples), so most mages are born to two mages, or at least one parent is magical.*

*Signs of magic are apparent at roughly 18 months of age (Age one and a half), but the signs are too subtle for anyone, except for mages who are trained to look at signs, to detect. The signs become noticeable to regular mages when the child is 10 or 11, at which point many magical children (Especially mage-born) are allowed to take a magical training course at school, designed to educate the child on magic and spellcasting. This course is put onto the child's schedule until about junior or senior year of high school, about 17 or 18 (I am ripping off Harry Potter for this).*

***Okay, back to actual needed stuff!***

Magicians would love it if the magical energies were stable, but it's not (Need something to balance it!): The magic flows around in a phenomenon called Magiflow.

The 12 elements have their own Magiflow cycles, usually based off of what their element is. The Magiflow has reservoirs that keep some of the magical energy in areas where the element has a huge influence. For example, the Fire Magiflow (Colloquially called the Magmaflow) has reservoirs in areas with lots of heat, like volcanoes, factories, and boilers. These reservoirs are called Magivoirs, and Magistreams (Streams of the same energy as the Magivoir) flow out in stronger amounts than the Magivoir. The Magistream has a 5 centimeter diameter and can extend for thousands of miles across Damarian's surface, usually 1 meter above the surface. When Magistreams of the same type cross, the streams make a pool of energy called a Magipool in 30 seconds, which is about 7 meters high and which has a 4 meter diameter.

However, like any touchy cycle, Magistreams can shift, especially farther from their source, in a phenomenon called the Magiflay. The Magistream will sometimes shift, sometimes mere cm, sometimes miles away. If a Magistream has Magipools, and it moves more than 3 meters away from the crossing that spawned a Magipool, the Magipool fades away over the course of from 2 hours to a second (Magipools that have been in an area for a while take longer to fade, but are rare). If a mage casts a spell of the same type as a Magipool, the Magipool fades instantly.

Nearly everywhere, multiple Magistream crossings of different energies form several Magipools, though huge groups of Magipools are extremely rare; Most Magipools have 3 or 4 other pools within a 500-meter radius. Magipools of the same type will merge into a larger one called a Magijunction if they are within 3 meters of each other, forming a larger Magipool of the smaller ones' type. The connection is usually 7 meters tall and 2 meters wide. The entire Magijunction counts as one Magipool, and fades as one when a mage casts a spell. The biggest advantage of a Magijunction is that even if a crossing that spawned part of the Magijunction is broken, the Magijunction will remain as long as a crossing of the same type as the Magijunction is in the Magijunction's area.

Truly massive Magijunctions are extremely rare; Roughly 1 in 3 million Magijunctions is larger than 4 Magijunctions, and Magijunctions composed of more than 16 Magipool areas (Megajunctions) are so rare, every single one is recorded into history. The largest one ever faded 45 years to the setting date, and was as composed of 1,000 Magipools and their connections (Its total area was 16 KILOMETERS, as every individual Magipool piece connects to a Magipool if it's close enough.

While surrounded by a Magipool, Magistrikes or Magivoir (Magistreams, being 5 cm wide, are too small to be useful) a mage can create spells of the corresponding types (Fireballs in Magmapools, tornadoes in Aeropools (Air Magiflow effects), storms in Electropools (Storm), etc). However, a mage can create a temporary Magiflow area in the area affected by their spells of the type the spell was. This temporary effect is called a Magistrike, and every cubic centimeter affected by the magic is part of the Magistrike. This means that is a mage launches a fireball at a mage enemy, and the enemy survives, the Magmastrike allows the enemy to launch a fireball back. A Magistrike lasts for 1 minute, or until a mage casts a spell of the corresponding element.

All mages are taught to be able to detect the Magiflow and be able to predict when a Magipool able of surrounding them (Magipools are typically the dimensions provided above, but can occasionally be smaller) will form within the next 30 seconds, with most young casters being correct roughly 35% of the time, and the most powerful archmages being able to predict Magipools correctly every time, and often can even learn the Magipool's type, with a roughly 45% accuracy rate.

**Here are what the typical spell of a type is, along with what the Magiflow name is for the element:**

Air (Aeroflow): Clouds, wind, flight, and sound. Illusions are possible with Windflow. Windvoirs occur in windy areas and mountains.

Darkness (Nightflow): Illusions, blindness, sleep effects, and invisibility. Nightvoirs are in dark areas and caves, and nighttime turns the entire world on the dark side of Damarian into a massive powerful Nightvoir, which makes Nightstreams across the day side.

Death (Necroflow): Necromancy, raising/animation of the dead, and spirit interaction. Necrovoirs are most common in areas where lots of people died, though even one corpse makes a tiny, very weak Nercovoir. Graveyards, battlefields, and hospitals (Because of euthanasia and surgery-related deaths) are the most powerful Necrovoirs..

Earth (Terraflow): Earth molding (Using dirt, sand, or rocks to form walls and structures), burrowing, and seismic effects. Terravoirs occur most common in rocky or sandy locations, like caves, deserts, mountains, and beaches.

Fire (Magmaflow): Fireballs and other fire-in-your-face-type magic. Magmavoirs form around volcanoes, factories, and other areas where it's hot.

Ice (Iceflow): Cryokinesis, snow creation, and other things Elsa from Disney's *Frozen* can do. Icevoirs form around ice, with small ice cubes making tiny, pathetic ones, and glaciers making massive, powerful Icevoirs. Mountains can also form them.

Life (Lifeflow): Healing, plant growth, shapeshifting, and natural things. Lifevoirs can form around wild animals, but they're weak (Why else would druids want to keep entire armies of animals?), plants make small Lifevoirs, and places of nature's beauty make the largest and most powerful.

Light (Dayflow): Light, radiant blasts, and mirages. Dayvoirs form around light sources, but a typical light bulb in a house makes a pathetic one. The day side of Damarian is one massive, ultra-powerful Dayvoir, with Daystreams on the night side of Damarian.

Psyche (Mindflow): Enchantments, charms, mind-affecting magic, planar movement, and space-time piercing effects (Like time travel, clairvoyance, and teleportation). Mindvoirs form and fade seemingly at random, though areas where events of powerful emotion (Like massacres, parties, and mosh pits) often form Mindvoirs, as do mental facilities.

Storm (Electroflow): Electricity, storms, and thunder. Electrovoirs form during storms, and stay in areas constantly attacked by storms.

War (Battleflow): Strength, combat, and weapon summoning. Battlevoirs almost always form during battle, with the Battlevoir becoming stronger and more permanent, and making mages in the Battlevoir feel more compelled to use War spells as the battle's outcome affects more of Damarian's future. Archmages can detect the Battlevoir becoming more powerful, even from thousands of miles away, and often use the increases as a prediction of how important the battle will be.

Water (Aquaflow): Aquakinesis, fish control, and liquefying. Aquavoirs form around any body of still water, but any body of water that is less than 20,441 liters total (Half the volume of a 12-by-24 foot swimming pool) makes makes a weaker Aquavoir. The oceans and seas of Damarian are one massive Aquavoir with their Aquastreams forming across land after rising out of the water.

In addition, a few factors make mages more powerful: female casters are more powerful than men, period; Groups of exactly 3 are most powerful, due to a phenomenon called the Rule of Three; Mages become more powerful as they age and experiment; and tattoos depicting a representative of an element (Cloud for Air, fire for Fire, etc) make the caster more powerful with the depicted element.

In combat, spellcasters choose 4 spells of regular power and 1 ultra-powerful spell (Like a fireball or massive storm) for use. The chosen list are the only spells a caster can use for 2 hours.

So, how will a typical magic fight between 2 groups of 3 mages each, 2 males and 1 female each, with a great area for all of the Magiflows to arise (Sunset by a seaside mountain, on which is a factory, by a forest with a mental facility, with a volcano offshore, on a rocky beach where, 5 years before, a major sea landing turned to be a massacre), what would their tactics be?

Comment: So if I am a mage and I cast a fire spell all the fire energy is used up in all the surrounding magi-whatnot potentially leaving water energy left? Is that right?  Are regular spells faster than ultra spells and if so how many regular spells can I cast before you cast an ultra? At the moment I am leaning towards fights being quick dumps of 12 spells (4 low level by each of the 3 party members) to nullify each type of magi-whatnot and then they wail on their foes with sticks.

Comment: Questions about tactics are off topic for this site because tactics are dictated by the specifics of the scenario. The specifics of any scenario is entirely up to you as the author, and as such questions about how a fight would play out isn't really about building the world.

Comment: A better question would be how your mages would affect battle tactics and combat in general. For example, if female mages are stronger than male mages, it seems there'd be more women involved in the military.

Comment: Also, can magivoirs and magistreams mix? Like for a hot spring, would that be a water/fire magivoir? Because otherwise, a battlefield will only have Battleflow. That said, if they _can_ mix, a battlefield, due to the intense emotions of warfare, will likely end up  being a War/Psyche magivoir....hmmm....

Comment: Most of the info about magipools -- and all the info about magistreams -- is unimportant to the question, since you only ask about combat when there are loads of different types of pools nearby.

Comment: @Alendyias, yes, Magiflows of different elements CAN mix for results like a Water/Fire Magivoir, and a battlefield is often a War/Psyche/Death Magivoir, especially after the battle is over, when lots of corpses are left. Once the bodies are gone, it turns into a War/Psyche, unless TONS of people died.

Comment: Interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mind Games.**

Tactically speaking, the most important feature of your magic system is how the mages cannot carry their spells around. Being able to re-use another mage's spell as it creates a magipool is a more complicated version of throwing heavy rocks at each other.

For example if there is a rock nearby you can run over, pick it up and throw it immediately. What you cannot do is pick up the rock and keep running.

**Downside:**
If you miss the throw you have just provided your enemy with a weapon. They can pick it up and throw it right back at you.

**Upsides:**

(1) You can throw a rock to influence your opponents. For example throw a rock near where your opponent is in cover, to lure them out and have your team-mates ambush them.

The fact that the Magistrikes expire means your opponent has only a brief window to deduce your intention and decide to use the rock or let it expire.

(2) You can move a rock into a better position by relaying with your team-mates, running towards the enemy while taking turns to throw the rock forwards. That means two mages working together are more effective tactically than working separately.

**More Stuff to Think About**

Something that will make a huge difference is the exact shape of  the Magistrikes.

- For example if I throw a fireball with a 5m radius explosion we get a
  Magistrike of that size I presume?
- What if I cast a lightning bolt in a straight line? Is the Magistrike also a straight line?
- What if I cast Fly on myself?
- What if I launch a big boulder at my opponent? Does the magistrike
  form from where I launched (near me) or where it lands?
- What if I cast a wind spell at my feet to launch the boulder
  forwards? Where does the Magistrike form?
- Mind Control?
- Summoning rain or fog?

The size and shape of the Magistrikes will all influence how risky
(danger of the spell being thrown back at you) each spell is.

- What if I cast Mass Healing Aura on myself and my friends nearby? Will that create a Magistrike around me? Can we use the Magistrike  to cast Mass Healing Aura s second time, creating a second Magistrike, and repeat forever?

Can mages typically cast several elements? This is important because, if I know my opponent only casts Ice spells there is no danger of them re-using my flame magistrikes.

Comment: Yes, a Magistrike's area is influenced by the spawning spell's effect. If a spell does not perform an AOE, its Magistrike travels with the affected object/creature. This means mind control and flight spells make trails. Rain and fog make an entire cubic area a Magistrike (For Water/Storm/Air elements).

Comment: Also, mages can cast any element, and a Magistrike for a larger effect makes less energy then the spell required to be cast. So, no infinite loops.

Comment: But what if I heal myself? Does the Magistrike appear right next to me?

Comment: Yes, a bubble of Magistrike appears centered on you, just big enough to surround you

Comment: So I can use it to cast heal over and over again? How about make myself faster, and stack that effect over and over again? Sounds very powerful.

Comment: No, the Magistrike has less elemental energy than the spell that made it. You can't stack speed spells over and over unless you have several Air Magipools or Magistrikes (The element for most speed spells) and you can't heal several times in a row.

Comment: Okay, the shrinking size means it's harder to collect a bunch of Magipools and move them closer to your opponents by casting them and collecting them. Probably it is still viable over short distances, if the Magistrike does not shrink too quickly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124068/discussion-between-the-darke-lorde-and-daron).